# Run a script on ONLY first root login in SLES 12

Tags: bash, shell, root, sles

I am trying to setup my SLES 12 system to run a script on ONLY the first root login into the SLES 12 system.  After that, root will never run the script again.  Also, I don't want any non-root users to run this script.

Anyone have any ideas on how I could accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use a flag file and a test condition for it.

```
script_function()
{
# what your script does
}

if [ -e /root/.flagfile ]
then
  : # do nothing
else
  script_function
  touch /root/.flagfile
fi
```

Then, place the script in your profile.d or .bash_login for only the root user.

Answer (score 0):

If it is **ESSENTIAL** that the script will execute only one time, there is a risk the flag file will be accidentally remove ,trigger re-run on the next login. As an alternative, consider flipping the condition, and potentially making the script non-executable, just in case.

During system config, create executable '~root/run-once.sh`, with '/path/to/script'.

Then in /etc/profile

```
if [ -x ~/run-once.sh ] ; then
    source ~/run-once.sh
    # Disable re-run with
    rm ~/run-once.sh
    # OR
    chmod -x ~/run-once.sh
fi
```

As a side effect, this approach make it possible to force other one-time login for other users, if needed.